# Upload and display PDF file saved in PostgreSQL using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, pdf

I have a project that **required** me to save a PDF file in the database (**literally save the file in the DB**, not the path). I'm using PostgreSQL 10 and Laravel 5.6. This is my migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('uploads', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('mime');
        $table->binary('data'); // generate a bytea column after running migration
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And below is the function in my controller to upload PDF file:

```
public function upload(Request $req)
{
  $name = pg_escape_string($_FILES['fpdf']['name']);
  $type = pg_escape_string($_FILES['fpdf']['type']);
  $data = pg_escape_bytea(file_get_contents($_FILES['fpdf']['tmp_name']));

  DB::table('uploads')
  ->insert(['name' => $name, 'mime' => $type, 'data' => $data]);

  return "success upload";
}
```

It is successfully uploaded the PDF file:
[Result showed in pgAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oZVE.png)

**But the problem is, the PDF file cannot be shown (download) in the browser.** This is the function in my controller to display the PDF file in the browser:

```
public function showPDF($id)
{
  $pdf = Upload::find($id);
  return view('upload/pdf', compact('pdf'));
}
```

The view file:

```
<?php
    $content = pg_unescape_bytea(stream_get_contents($pdf->data));
    echo "<embed src='data:". $pdf->mime .";base64,".base64_encode($content)."' />";
?>
```

And the output is:
[Output for displaying the PDF file in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MakUd.png)

---

I've tried to find the solution by browsing so many questions on stackoverflow and other Q&A websites with the keyword "upload and display PDF file stored in the PostgreSQL DB", but unfortunately I couldn't find any answers on how to display the PDF file.

There is a video I've found on YouTube ([Insert File into MySQL Blob with PHP](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfobCv4YBdk)), but after trying it, still no luck.

My question is, how can I display/download a saved PDF file in the PostgreSQL database on the browser using Laravel 5.6 framework?

==================================================================

I modified my showPDF function according to Devon recommendation, but I got the following output:

[image: latest output]

And this is the modified showPDF function:

```
public function showPDF($id)
{
    $pdf = Upload::find($id);
    $content = pg_unescape_bytea(stream_get_contents($pdf->data));
    return response($content)->header('Content-Type', $pdf->mime);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using escape string functions?  Do you really want to embed or just have them download it?

Comment: Hi Devon, I would like to do either one of it, but I prefer to download the PDF file.

Comment: You really shouldn't combine pg_ functions with Laravel.  Stop using escape string functions anyways, even outside of Laravel you should be using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have PDF readers built in these days, there's usually no reason to use embed unless you want to actually embed the PDF amongst other content.

For this, you should just be able to return the response from the controller with the header set for the Content-Type:

```
return response($content)->header('Content-Type', $pdf->mime);
```

Comment: I tried your code in my showPDF function, but it gave me an error: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "resource" given.

Comment: I modified the showPDF function, but now the error is failed to load PDF document (details on the question above). What am I missing?

Comment: Your first message indicates $content wasn't a string.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, after trying several combinations. And here's my solution:

Migration file:

```
Schema::create('uploads', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('mime');
        $table->text('data');
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

What I did in migration file, is changed the datatype for column data, previously I used **binary**, and here I use **text**.

Function in my controller to upload the PDF file:

```
public function upload()
{
    $name = $_FILES['fpdf']['name'];
    $mime = $_FILES['fpdf']['type'];
    $content = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['fpdf'['tmp_name']));

    $up = new Upload;

    $up->name = $name;
    $up->mime = $mime;
    $up->content = $content;

    $up->save();

    return redirect('upload');
}
```

I encode the PDF file using **base64_encode()** function. And here's the method to show the PDF file:

```
public function showPDF($id)
{
    $pdf = Upload::find($id);

    $content = base64_decode($pdf->content);
    return response($content)->header('Content-Type', $pdf->mime); // thanks to Devon
}
```

View file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form Upload PDF File</h1>

    <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf

        <br>
        <input type="file" name="fpdf">
        <br> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <h3>List of PDFs</h3>

    @foreach($pdfs as $row)
        <a href="show/{{ $row->id }}" target="_blank"> {{ $row->name }} </a>
        <br>
    @endforeach
</body>
</html>
```

This is my solution for now. I know it might not be the best way to handle file upload, but it works. Any suggestion to make the code better and secure are welcome.